# Does TensorFlow support binary/boolean tensors with type: 1 bit?

Tags: machine-learning, binary, boolean, tensorflow, bit

Does TensorFlow support boolean tensors where every element occupies just 1 bit (not 8) ? Can I define large tensors ~100 MB ?

Where can I read about it ?

Couldn't find anything searching on Internet, thats why I'm asking.

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow DT_BOOL tensors map to the underlying C++ bool type, which does not take 1 bit of memory.

You can implement your own operations on a Variant dtype, but it requires quite a bit of C++ coding.